# libGDX game crashing on iOS 7

Tags: java, ios, libgdx

My libGDX game has suddenly started crashing on iOS 7.0.3 and 7.0.4. It seemingly runs fine on Android, desktop and older versions of iOS.

The error message I get is:

> An exception was thrown by the type initializer for
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap
>   (System.TypeInitializationException)

And here's the full crash report: http://pastebin.com/DdFk1BSM

This happens immediately when starting the game (the gray splash screen expands from the app icon, and then it force quits).

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old Xamarin based version of libGDX did not work on the newest iOS versions. The solution was to upgrade the project from IKVM to RoboVM: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3063